# fdisk shows the partition table of a device, but udev doesn't create the device

Tags: mount

I'm trying to mount a external USB hard drive. Specifically, a USB key. But `udev` doesn't show the partition on the drive.

I'm running Debian 10 (buster) with a stock kernel, namely `4.19.0-6-amd64`.

`fdisk` reports

```
root@orwell:/mnt# fdisk -l /dev/sdh
Disk /dev/sdh: 1.9 GiB, 2001076224 bytes, 3908352 sectors
Disk model: Cruzer Blade
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x03b1e8fa

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdh1        2048 3908351 3906304  1.9G  b W95 FAT32
```

But if I try to mount the partition, I get

```
root@orwell:/mnt# mount -t vfat /dev/sdh1 joseph
mount: /mnt/joseph: special device /dev/sdh1 does not exist.
```

While this probably isn't very relevant, the partition also does not seem to have a UUID. At least, the device does not show up in `blkid`.

`journalctl` shows the following logs, on plugging in the device.

```
Nov 06 19:01:09 orwell kernel: usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
Nov 06 19:01:09 orwell kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5567, bcdDevice= 1.00
Nov 06 19:01:09 orwell kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Nov 06 19:01:09 orwell kernel: usb 1-1: Product: Cruzer Blade
Nov 06 19:01:09 orwell kernel: usb 1-1: Manufacturer: SanDisk
Nov 06 19:01:09 orwell kernel: usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 20063486020EF1B285D3
Nov 06 19:01:09 orwell kernel: usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Nov 06 19:01:09 orwell kernel: scsi host11: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
Nov 06 19:01:09 orwell mtp-probe[30090]: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-1"
Nov 06 19:01:09 orwell mtp-probe[30090]: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Nov 06 19:01:10 orwell mtp-probe[30094]: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-1"
Nov 06 19:01:10 orwell mtp-probe[30094]: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Nov 06 19:01:10 orwell kernel: scsi 11:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer Blade     1.01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Nov 06 19:01:10 orwell kernel: sd 11:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg9 type 0
Nov 06 19:01:10 orwell kernel: sd 11:0:0:0: [sdh] 3908352 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 GB/1.86 GiB)
Nov 06 19:01:10 orwell kernel: sd 11:0:0:0: [sdh] Write Protect is off
Nov 06 19:01:10 orwell kernel: sd 11:0:0:0: [sdh] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
Nov 06 19:01:10 orwell kernel: sd 11:0:0:0: [sdh] No Caching mode page found
Nov 06 19:01:10 orwell kernel: sd 11:0:0:0: [sdh] Assuming drive cache: write through
Nov 06 19:01:11 orwell kernel: sd 11:0:0:0: [sdh] Attached SCSI removable disk
Nov 06 19:01:11 orwell systemd[1]: Starting usbmount@dev-sdh.service...
Nov 06 19:01:11 orwell usbmount[30113]: loaded usbmount configurations
Nov 06 19:01:11 orwell usbmount[30114]: usbmount is disabled, see /etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf
Nov 06 19:01:11 orwell systemd[1]: Started usbmount@dev-sdh.service.
Nov 06 19:01:11 orwell audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj==unconfined msg='unit=usbmount@dev-sdh comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason the Linux kernel isn't recognizing the partition table, so it doesn't know there should be an `sdh1`. Unless you've done something weird (like compiling a kernel w/o DOS partition table support), that probably means the partition table format isn't exactly as expected by the kernel (`fdisk` is a different implementation of parsing the partition table, so that could be why fdisk is OK with it). Likely re-writing the partition table with `fdisk` (etc.) would fix it.

However, if you want to mount the partition w/o re-writing the table (e.g., to not modify the disk), then you can manually feed the partition details to the kernel with `addpart`:

```
addpart /dev/sdh 1 2048 3906304
#                ^   ^     ^ 
# partition#────┘   |      \
#              start sector  length (sectors)   ← both from fdisk -l output
```

After running that (and waiting a tiny bit for udev), you should have a `/dev/sdh1`, which you can go ahead and mount.